# Android OpenGL Loading Screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, progress-bar

I`m working on OpenGL tester program for Android. So i have pretty havy scene with 68 objects, each one has its own class. I`m also have Activity, GLView and GLRenderer classes. All objects declared in GLRenderer like so:

```
   private final lToe lToe = new lToe();
   private final rToe rToe = new rToe();
   private final pelvis pelvis = new pelvis();
   private final waist waist = new waist();
   private final chest chest = new chest();
```

My problem is - when i create GLView in Activity with lines:

```
            showDialog(0);
            GLView view;
            view = new GLView(this);
            setContentView(view);
```

my application stops responding for about 15 secs, it not showing my loading dialog("showDialog(0);"), placed in dedicated thread, i even have "Not responding Stop/Wait" dialog every time i launching application. So is there some way to keep UI responding and progress bar showing properly, while loading ? (Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the scene for the first time (create the view), you should do it on a separate thread, then call runOnUiThread() to pop up a dialog on the UI thread. I would also look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as it will save you time.